# When to delete the windows security attributes after creating a event/mutex

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I am creating a mutex using some security attributes, my question is when should i delete this SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure.
should i delete it immediately after creating the mutex, or should i wait untill the mutex handle is closed.

```
Approach 1.
Create Security attributes
CreateMutex using the above Security attributes
do some task....
Close mutex
release Security attributes

Approach 2.
Create Security attributes
CreateMutex using the above Security attributes
release Security attributes
do some task....
Close mutex
```

Which one is the best way to do??

Comment: There is no need to allocate this structure dynamically at all. Consider it rather a way of passing function parameters.

Comment: Actually i have a pre-written code, that i cannot change, it allocates the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES dynamically/

Comment: If you can't change it, why do you ask? Anyhow, the answer should be clear.

Comment: You can deallocate the memory as soon as CreateMutex returns.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the allocation and release functions for security attributes are pre-written, i am using them, to create mutex in my module. Anyways, thanks for your suggestions. :) :)

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the answer, can you please post this as an answer with relevant references to some trusted sources. I can mark it correct. :)

Comment: If someone can scare up a reference I'll let them post an answer.  This is more a "common knowledge" or a "it stands to reason" question than a "here is the reference" question IMO. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you closely look at the API of CreateMutex, it takes the pointer to Security attributes, than, this makes me think, that, what if these pointers are used, while signalling, non-signalling and closing the mutex.
"common knowledge" :p

Comment: The documentation should explicitly say when a buffer has to remain valid after the call completes - there may be cases where it doesn't, but I'm not aware of any.  There are also a few reasons why it's unlikely in this case.  Firstly, the information in the structure is only used when creating the mutex.  Secondly, if the structure did have to remain valid for the lifetime of the mutex, what would happen when the process exits?  (Plus, of course, I've been using CreateMutex and similar functions for years and using a statically-scoped structure has never caused any problems.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston i accept, " if the structure did have to remain valid for the lifetime of the mutex, what would happen when the process exits? " this line proves that security attributes can be released immediately.. :)
Thanks a lot.. :) :)